# Couldn't find TextInput features documentation?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native and having difficulty finding some features documentation regarding `TextInput`.

On react-native site it is mentioned about `TextInput`:

> Props provide configurability for several features, such as
>   auto-correction, auto-capitalization, placeholder text, and different
>   keyboard types, such as a numeric keypad.

But I couldn't find documentation that explains these features `auto-correction`, `auto-capitalization`, `placeholder text` like what all the parameters they take? what are the deault values? are they required parameter? and how they exactly work.

Is there somewhere I can read about these features implementation?

I'm trying to set prop-types for these props and want to know what kind of data they expect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when `TextInput` is rendered it displays the default keyboard(ios and android), in which autocapitalization of first letter is already defined.

In order to remove auto-capitalisation of first letter, you write the property like this:

```
<TextInput 
 autoCapitalize={false} />
```

Similarly, you can add properties like `autoCorrect={false}` if you need not auto correction of words.

Here are all the properties for `TextInput` you can use:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/next/textinput.html

Comment: Thanks. I read this link and I was confused as I didn't know about this behaviour. It would be great if I can find some resources where I can read more them about. On the rn site, they just mentioned the names. Nothing else.

Comment: they are not mentioned in the props documentation below.

Comment: I can provide you the code where I have used most of the properties. Basically Every property is used like the way explained in answer. If you want to pass a string that will look like this `value='Hello'` otherwise you will use `value={true or false}` inside a curly phrase. If you want to use a function then `onChange={()=>{this.setState({text:text})}}`

Hope I am able to explain well!

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is means that there is official documentation that explain these in details, maybe with examples.